# Scrapy is showing notImplementedError and I don't know why

Tags: python, scrapy

My Scrapy code doesn't work and I am not sure why. My spider is a test to crawl the Game of Throne subreddit on Reddit.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy


class Redditbot2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'redditbot2'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/']


def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.selector.xpath('//h2/text()').extract()
    votes = response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="_1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p80D0"]/test()').extract()
    time = response.selector.xpath('//a[@class="_3jOxDPIQ0KaOWpzvSQo-1s"]/text()').extract()
    comments = response.selector.xpath('//span[@class="FHCV02u6Cp2zYL0fhQPsO"])/text()').extract()

    for item in zip(titles, votes, time, comments):
        scraped_info = {
            'title': titles[0],
            'vote': votes[1],
            'time': time[2],
            'comments': comments[3],
        }
        yield scraped_info
```

And here is a log of the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 90, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
NotImplementedError: Redditbot2Spider.parse callback is not defined
```

The Redditbot2Spider.parse method is there, so I don't get why it is saying that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Your code has an indentation problem, the `parse` method is in the same level as the class is, so the interpreter doesn't realize that it is a member of the class. You have to make an indent in the `parse` method:

```
class Redditbot2Spider(scrapy.Spider): 
    name = 'redditbot2'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/']
    def parse(self, response): 
        titles = response.selector.xpath('//h2/text()').extract()
        #etc.
```

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful!