# ModuleNotFound error using Scrapy. Spider not found

Tags: python, mongodb, module, scrapy

running into an ModuleNotFound Error with a web-crawler I put together based on a project tutorial. I got the crawler running fine but once I added code to extract the data and store it in MongoDB database Im running into an issue when initiating the crawler of 'ModuleNotFoundError' and looks like says cannot locate module for my spider (name-'stackspider'). Since the spider was running fine before not sure where the gap is.

Didnt want to overload with code for first question. How can I resolve this ModuleNotFound Error?

If additional details needed or code happy to supply. Thanks for the help.

[this is the link to tutorial I used to create the scraper project] (https://realpython.com/web-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/#scrapy-project)

```
2020-04-14 08:23:28 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 89, in crawl
self.engine = self._create_engine()
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 103, in _create_engine
return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
mwcls = load_object(clspath)
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 50, in load_object
mod = import_module(module)
    File "/Users/blouie/.conda/envs/GoScrape/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stackspider'
```

Code for my spider (stackspider.py)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from bigscrape.items import BigscrapeItem


class StackspiderSpider(Spider):
    name = 'stackspider'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ["http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=newest"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

    def parse(self, response):
        #item = BigscrapeItem()
        questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="summary"]/h3')
        for question in questions:
            item = BigscrapeItem()
            item['title'] = question.xpath(
            'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/text()').get()
            item['url'] = question.xpath(
            'a[@class="question-hyperlink"]/@href').get()

            yield item
```

Comment: Please add your spider's code to the question (or a preview of it) and tell us how you run the spider

Comment: @thirdDeveloper Edited code in the original question with spider's code. Running on MacOS in terminal using  $ scrapy crawl stackspider

Comment: Your code has indentation problem. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173900/1578952

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Went back to spider code and realized indentation was there. Think that indentation problem was a factor of being new to formatting code correctly on stackoverflow. Still getting same error unfortunately.

Comment: Try run `scrapy list` in the command line. What is the output?

Comment: Ran`(tutorial-env) (GoScrape) blouie@blouie1-macbook bigscrape % scrapy list`      Came back with `stackspider` , thats its @thirdDeveloper

Comment: Here's a github link for the code -  [https://github.com/BLouie2/StackSpider]